# Display a | character between CRUD View Action links

Tags: c#, view, asp.net-mvc-5, character, actionlink

In a C# MVC5 Internet Application View, how can I display the `|` character between my CRUD View Action links when the links are in an if statement?

Here is my code:

```
<td>
    @if (item.mapLocationItemType.Equals("Video Gallery"))
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "MapLocationVideoGallery", new { id = item.Id }, null) @|
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", "MapLocationVideoGallery", new { id = item.Id }, null) @|
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "MapLocationVideoGallery", new { id = item.Id }, null) @|
        @Html.ActionLink("Videos", "Index", "MapLocationVideo", new { mapLocationVideoGalleryId = item.Id }, null)
    }
</td>
```

Here is the error:

```
Parser Error Message: "|" is not valid at the start of a code block.  Only identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid.
```

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

I have removed the @ character as well as placed the | on each new line, and I get a compiler message each way.

Here is my code:

```
<td>
    @if (item.mapLocationItemType.Equals("Video Gallery"))
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "MapLocationVideoGallery", new { id = item.Id }, null) 
        |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", "MapLocationVideoGallery", new { id = item.Id }, null) 
        |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "MapLocationVideoGallery", new { id = item.Id }, null) 
        |
        @Html.ActionLink("Videos", "Index", "MapLocationVideo", new { mapLocationVideoGalleryId = item.Id }, null)
    }
</td>

<td>
    @if (item.mapLocationItemType.Equals("Video Gallery"))
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "MapLocationVideoGallery", new { id = item.Id }, null) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", "MapLocationVideoGallery", new { id = item.Id }, null) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "MapLocationVideoGallery", new { id = item.Id }, null) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Videos", "Index", "MapLocationVideo", new { mapLocationVideoGalleryId = item.Id }, null)
    }
</td>
```

The error is a compilation error, with the following message:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1513: } expected
```

Comment: just remove @ before |....

Comment: @| - should be replace with simple | and should be put on a newLine  (every @|)

Comment: just post full view there is problem somewhere else..

Comment: just see my update it will work..@user3736648

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work.

```
<td>
@if (item.mapLocationItemType.Equals("Video Gallery"))
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "MapLocationVideoGallery", new { id = item.Id }, null) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", "MapLocationVideoGallery", new { id = item.Id }, null) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "MapLocationVideoGallery", new { id = item.Id }, null) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Videos", "Index", "MapLocationVideo", new { mapLocationVideoGalleryId = item.Id }, null)
}
```

**Just remove the @ before |**

OR Just write it as :

```
<td>
@if (item.mapLocationItemType.Equals("Video Gallery"))
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "MapLocationVideoGallery", new { id = item.Id }, null)  @:|
    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", "MapLocationVideoGallery", new { id = item.Id }, null)  @:|
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "MapLocationVideoGallery", new { id = item.Id }, null)  @:|
    @Html.ActionLink("Videos", "Index", "MapLocationVideo", new { mapLocationVideoGalleryId = item.Id }, null)
}
```

Comment: @user3736648...as i told you in my comment remove the @ before |

Comment: Now the actionlinks are at the top of the controller, rather than to the side of each item in the view list.

Comment: @user3736648...i think that i solved your problem..if you have another problem just post another question...thankzzz....

Answer (score 0):

@| - should be replace with simple | and should be put on a newLine (every @|)